# Assign value to typedef struct

Tags: c++, c

I try to assign value to a `State` like this

```
typedef struct States
{
    int S[3][3];
    int empty = 0;
} State;


State Goal;
Goal.S = { {0, 1, 2},{3, 4, 5},{6, 7, 8} };
```

But this not working and appear some syntax error like "missing ';'..."

Comment: Are you compiling C or C++ code? It is invalid as C.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays.

Comment: use a loop to assign values to an array in `c`

Comment: Please clarify the language! Read the descriptions of the two tags (or, any tag) that you apply before applying them. SO only gives you suggestions. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 4):

If you want to initialize an array with values, you should do it when it's being constructed.

```
State Goal = { {{0, 1, 2},{3, 4, 5},{6, 7, 8}}, 0 };
```